# Can I pass a UIButton in scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, nstimer

I need to disable a button for 2.56 seconds, long after control is returned to the user. I am using the following code where theButton is type UIButton, defined at the beginning of the routine with

UIButton *theButton = sender;

and later calling the following which will update a label and then, hopefully, enable the button. Updating the label works perfectly but it crashes when trying to enable the button so I must be passing the UIButton incorrectly. Can anyone give me an example / correct me on this?

```
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.56
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(updateLabel:)
                                   userInfo:theButton
                                    repeats:NO];
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are writing `updateLabel`: method as follows

```
-(void) updateLabel:(NSTimer *)timer1
{
   //your other code...
    [(UIButton *)[timer1 userInfo] setEnabled:YES];
  //your other code
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Nope. THanks. that make so darn much sense. I had  -(void) updateLabel(UIButton *)theButton        Thank you so much. Hope I can make it up to you!!